# Make dropdown parent link clickable for smaller devices and hide dropdown in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with a site using HTML5 and CSS3, and using a Bootstrap 3.2.

I have a dropdown for shopping cart item in desktop view. However, I need to remove this dropdown for small mobile device and instead make the cart link clickable.

Currently, the cart link is not clickable as it is opening a dropdown on click!

Can anyone advise how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually hold two attributes to the **CART**

This doesn't show on mobile

```
<div class="hidden-xs dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Cart
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
...
</div>
```

In the next line hold a link, this doesn't show upon any desktop screens/small screen (tablets)

```
<a class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="cart">Cart</a>
```

I hope this what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
            .dropdown-menu {
                display: block;
            }
        }

        /* Landscape phones and smaller */
        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            .dropdown-menu {
                display: block;
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/wvLSlHhbnw)

Comment: I tried this one but it keeps drop down menu opens on smaller screens. What I want is to hide dropdown, and make parent link clickable. This doesn't help me, but thank you for your help and idea, may be I will use it somewhere else.